# Javascript Redirect using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, redirect, settimeout

I have a button that I want to run a piece of script and then redirect, however nothing is happening

I have another page that uses similar code and that works. but this one just isn't working

Code to work:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='$.get("features.php",{ cmd: "confirm_order", id: "<?php echo $o_id; ?>", name: "<?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>" email: "<?php echo $_SESSION['user_email']; ?>"};setTimeout("window.location.href=order.php?order_id=<?php echo $o_id;?>", 100);' class="button">
```

Code that already works on a different page:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='$.get("features.php",{ cmd: "remove", id: "<?php echo $o_id; ?>", prod: "<?php echo $row_prod['prod_id']; ?>" });setTimeout("window.location.href=window.location.href", 100);'>
```

Now I know it's all to do with my setTimeout, I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**

Link now:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button confirm">Confirm</a>
```

Code below the link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a .confirm').on('click',function(e){
    $.get("features.php",{
        cmd: "confirm_order",
        id: "<?php echo $o_id; ?>",
        name: "<?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>",
        email: "<?php echo $_SESSION['user_email']; ?>"
    });
    setTimeout(
        function(){
            window.location = "order.php?order_id=<?php echo $o_id;?>" 
        },
    100);
});
</script>
```

which still isn't working, and is rendering the `\"` in the code

Comment: I really would not put so much code into an HTML attribute. Create a function and if you really cannot assign the function via JavaScript, call it in attribute.

Comment: Your code is a tad hard to read... this could be adding to your problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with Felix Kling comment that you shouldn't add that much code to an html attribute. I see that you're using jQuery so why don't you just add this to your javascript code:

```
$('a .button').on('click',function(e){
    $.get("features.php",{ 
          cmd: "confirm_order",
          id: "<?php echo $o_id; ?>",
          name: "<?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>", // you were missing this comma 
          email: "<?php echo $_SESSION['user_email']; ?>"
        }).done(function(){
             window.setTimeout( function(){
                 window.location = "order.php?order_id=<?php echo $o_id;?>";
             }, 100 );
        }); // you where missing this parenthesis          

  e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: Hmm. Thanks I gave that a go but it still just sits there. I've edited my original post to show you my updates

Comment: is there something I need to add into my link to get this to run?

Comment: I eddietd the setTimeOut first argument so that it receives a function, that way you won't have to worry about characters messing up your links, also i dont think it's necessary for you to add `window.location.href`, `window.location` will do

Comment: Thanks but when I click the link still nothing happens? Am I suppose to add something to my link?

Comment: did you removed `e.preventDefault()` ?

Comment: try the way i just putted it, i don't know if you can get away mixing that php code in your `window.location`, also check if you're getting any errors in firebug or chrome developer tools console

Comment: it still didn't work, but I went and put the updated code back into the link and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting your file name in between `"` (You can escape it using `\"`):

```
setTimeout("window.location.href=\"order.php?order_id=<?php echo $o_id;?>\";", 100);
```

Your file name is a string. Otherwise JavaScript would expect a variable. That is why `setTimeout("window.location.href=window.location.href;", 100);` works.

I think there is also one comma missing:

```
name: "<?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>" email: "<?php echo $_SESSION['user_email']; ?>"
```

should be `name: "<?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>", email: "<?php echo $_SESSION['user_email']; ?>"`

You are also missing a parenthesis. Try to change your code to:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='$.get("features.php",{ cmd: "confirm_order", id: "<?php echo $o_id; ?>", name: "<?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>", email: "<?php echo $_SESSION['user_email']; ?>"});setTimeout("window.location.href=\"order.php?order_id=<?php echo $o_id;?>\";", 100);return false;' class="button">
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that but since the entire function is in between `'` it doesn't work, and when I try `\'` it just breaks.

Comment: The function is in `"`, not `'`, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The escape `'` to `\"`. Updated again.

Comment: Sorry I meant the onClick. And then when I tried using `\"` it rendered that in the code.

Answer (score 2):

try out this

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
redirectTime = "1500";
redirectURL = "http://www.natural-environment.com";
function timedRedirect() {
    setTimeout("location.href = redirectURL;",redirectTime);
}
</script>
```